# Problems with Sqlachemy. Can't understand the difference

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I have the following code

```
def update(project_id, code, description):

    if project_id is None:
        raise exception

    with session_handler() as session:
        project = session.query(Project).filter_by(project_id=project_id).first()
        project_upd = session.query(Project).filter_by(project_id=project_id)

    if project is None:
        raise ProjectDoesntExist(f"Project {project_id} does not exist.")
    data = _build_update_data(code, description)

    if  not data:
        raise ValueError("No code or description provided")

    project_upd.update(data)
```

So if I replace `project_upd.update(data)`  with `project.update(data)` it gives the following error

> Attribute Error: Project object has no attribute update.

How I can use only one variable?

Answer (score 2):

Though the `Project` model is omitted, it is clear that it has no method `update()` – which is the norm. The difference is that `project` is bound to a `Project` object, and `project_upd` to a [`Query`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html) object. In other words the former represents a single row in the table mapped to an object, while the latter represents a query against that table.

Your options are:

1. Issue an UPDATE statement only and check if it matched any rows, raise if not.
2. Fetch the row / object [for update](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.with_for_update), check if it existed and raise if not, do the update.

I assume that `session_handler()` commits, if no exception was raised. If that is not the case, add an explicit `session.commit()` as necessary.

### 1. Single UPDATE statement

```
def update(project_id, code, description):
    if project_id is None:
        raise exception

    data = _build_update_data(code, description)

    if not data:
        raise ValueError("No code or description provided")

    with session_handler() as session:
        row_count = session.query(Project).\
            filter_by(project_id=project_id).\
            update(data)

        if not row_count:
            raise ProjectDoesntExist(f"Project {project_id} does not exist.")
```

### 2. Fetch and update

```
def update(project_id, code, description):
    if project_id is None:
        raise exception

    data = _build_update_data(code, description)

    if not data:
        raise ValueError("No code or description provided")

    with session_handler() as session:
        # Fetch FOR UPDATE so that no concurrent updates may proceed in between
        # getting the `Project` instance and actually updating it.
        project = session.query(Project).\
            filter_by(project_id=project_id).\
            with_for_update().\
            first()

        if project is None:
            raise ProjectDoesntExist(f"Project {project_id} does not exist.")

        for attr, val in data.items():
            setattr(project, attr, val)
```

Locking with `FOR UPDATE` might be a bit unnecessary in this case, since the new values don't seem to depend on previous state of the object. Still, it is something to keep in mind.